# Moving from Ning to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, ning

**description:**
i have a project that i will make on WordPress...

the people have there data on Ning CMS..

**My Question:**
1- how to get data in the Ning and move it to WordPress?
2- is it right choice to make website on WordPress and move data from
   Ning to WordPress?

Thanks and and waits the answer ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use BuddyPress to use Ning-like social networking functionality in WordPress. http://buddypress.org

You can then use the Ning-To-BuddyPress importer to import your users and their data:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-from-ning/

Whether it's the right choice depends on a lot of stuff. Your users might not want to move to a different server and away from Ning, but ultimately you'll have more freedom if you do (I.e., not confined by Microsoft's TOS; all WP plugins available; ability to use WP's network mode to create a blog network; lots of stuff). Also, with Ning's announcement that it's getting rid of their free tier, WP'll almost definitely be cheaper (See: http://techcrunch.com/2010/04/15/nings-bubble-bursts-no-more-free-networks-cuts-40-of-staff/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ning API](http://developer.ning.com/docs/ningapi/1.0/index.html) to bulk-import blog posts into a Ning site. There isn't a WordPress specific tool, but there are some client libraries on [Ning's GitHub page](http://github.com/ning) to get your started. Note that it isn't possible to create members on your site, so you can't auto-import authors from your WordPress blog.